# How to create reusable custom block templates or duplicate existing blocks?

Tags: blocks

Drupal noob here.

Problem: Unable to reuse blocks created using Bootstrap Layouts module; being forced to manually re-enter data in order to duplicate a block in a new locaion.

Details and any research: Custom blocks seem to be made for reusability, but I'm struggling to find and insert any of the previously created blocks into new pages using the layout builder

Tried: searched Stack, Drupal forums and Google for "unable to reuse drupal custom blocks" and similar queries; read through what I understand of the Drupal and Bootstrap Layouts documentation.

Attached image shows an example of a custom grid block ("What We Do") which I'd like to be able to insert on a different page; unable to find it in any kind of list/library when in the target page layout builder. Forced to recreate it from scratch. Surely there's a way!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inline custom content blocks created on-the-fly inside a node's layout builder are intentionally not reuseable.

To create reuseable custom content blocks, go to to the custom block library `/admin/content/block` (if Drupal v10) or `/admin/structure/block/block-content` (if Drupal v9) and create the block there. The blocks created here are the reuseable ones.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Hudri.